# Google Sheets: how to sum a dynamic range across columns using a variable to determine range length

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to write a formula in Google Sheets that will enable me to sum a range of values across columns, where I can manipulate the number of cells to be summed across the column with a variable. For example:

- if my variable is 5, then I want to sum(D3:H3);
- and if my variable is 9, then I want to sum(D3:L3)

Furthermore, I want a formula that I can drag across columns so that the range it's summing moves relative to the cell the formula is in. In the example above with the variable=5:

- the formula in cell A3 would be sum(D3:H3);
- and the formula in cell B3 would be sum(E3:I3)
- etc.

I created a [sample spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/157-AoL98TB_D78yGCWtjf3_ThPaXEfaL2U4ogzZGr_w/edit#gid=0) for more context.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a sheet ("Erik Help"). See formula in B5:P5.

Here is the B5 formula (which was then dragged across to P5):

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(FILTER($B$1:$1,COLUMN($B$1:$1)>(COLUMN()-$B$4),COLUMN($B$1:$1)<=COLUMN())))`

There may be an array approach. But since you have such limited data, this is just as effective with less time investment required to develop the solution.

In plain English, the formula reads "Sum the numbers from B1:1 where the column is greater than `X` rows back and no greater than the current column" (where `X` is the value set in B4).

Comment: Thanks @Erik, that works! I still need to figure out how to adopt it for my actual use case based on this simplified example, I'll reply if I hit any roadblocks. Cheers-

Answer (score 0):

paste in column B and drag to the right:

```
=IF(COLUMN()-1<$B1, "-", SUM(INDIRECT(
 ADDRESS(3, COLUMN()-($B1-1))&":"&
 ADDRESS(3, COLUMN()))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your attempt @player0 - but maybe the spreadsheet I provided wasn't clear because the formula you created is adding up multiples of the variable onto a beginning value. But I'm trying to sum a dynamic range of the values in question. I've updated the spreadsheet to clarify the question.